# PHP - Array to string conversion using form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Hello I am yousing form to insert new values into query. 
Error which i got is:**Array to string conversion**. 
What should I change to not get this error?

Thank you

```
if( isset($_POST["new_log"]) ){

//mysql_real_escape_string - ochrana proti mysql injection

$name       = $_POST["name"];
$surname    = $_POST["surname"];
$password   = $_POST["password"];
$email      = $_POST["email"];
$salary     = $_POST["salary"];
$msaving    = $_POST["msaving"];
$mfixpayment = $_POST["mfixpayment"];
$lastupdate = $_POST["lastupdate"];
$bio        = $_POST["bio"];
$money      = $_POST["money"];

$new_log=" INSERT INTO login SET `name`='$name', `surname`='$surname', `password`='$password', `email`='$email', `salary`='$salary', `msaving`='$msaving', `mfixpayment`='$mfixpayment', `lastupdate`='$lastupdate', `bio`='$bio', `money`='$money' ";

mysql_query( $new_log ) or die( mysql_error() );

}
```

here I am inserting new values by form

```
    echo ' <form method="post"> ';  
    echo ' meno:                <input type="text" name="name['. $row_log["id"] .']" >  <br />';
    echo ' priezvisko:          <input type="text" name="surname['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' heslo:               <input type="text" name="password['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' e-mail:              <input type="text" name="email['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' vyplata:             <input type="number" name="salary['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' chcem mesačne ušetriť <input type="number" name="msaving['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' platím každý mesiac: <input type="number" name="mfixpayment['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' posledná mena:       <input type="date" name="lastupdate['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' niečo o sebe:        <input type="text" name="bio['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo ' mám na účte:         <input type="number" name="money['. $row_log["id"] .']">  <br />';
    echo "<br />";

    echo '<input type="submit" name="new_log" value="Pridať nového užívateľa" >';
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: All of your `$_POST` values are arrays.  That's what `name="name['. $row_log["id"] .']"` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name       = $_POST["name"];
```

should be

```
$name       = $_POST["name"][$id];
```

---

Alternatively, output this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" >
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="name['. $row_log["id"] .']" >
```